# If body class is equals to menu li class add class to li?

Tags: jquery, javascript, addclass

For example if body has class dummy... and in menu if li has same class... the new class should be added to li.. plz tell me how to do it in jQuery..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, here's how:

```
$("body.dummy li.dummy").addClass("new");
```

The selector `body.dummy li.dummy` selects all `<li>` tags that have the same `dummy` class as the `<body>`, and then add the `new` class to them.

http://api.jquery.com/addClass/

Answer (score 1):

```
if($("body").hasClass("dummy") && $("#menu li").hasClass("dummy")){
    $("#menu li").addClass("yourclass");
}
```

not sure what your menu ID name is, but this should get you going

Comment: hi joel,
thanks for reply it worked fine but my menu is dynamic so i cant mention class name... is there any other solution for my query..

Answer (score 1):

```
$("body.dummy li.dummy").addClass("newclass")
```